# How to print mysql query data into php multidimensional array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following format of php array:

```
$data = array(
  array(
 'label' => 'Sale',
 'color' => '#28d8b2',
 'data'  =>
    array(
       array('Jan', 27),
       array('Feb', 82),
       array('Mar', 56),
       array('Apr', 14),
       array('May', 28),
       array('Jun', 77),
       array('Jul', 23),
       array('Aug', 49),
       array('Sep', 81),
       array('Oct', 20),
       array('Nov', 23),
       array('Dec', 99)
    )
  )
);
```

And I want to put my data that query from mysql table to the sub array above as follow:

```
array(
       array('Jan', 27),
       array('Feb', 82),
       array('Mar', 56),
       array('Apr', 14),
       array('May', 28),
       array('Jun', 77),
       array('Jul', 23),
       array('Aug', 49),
       array('Sep', 81),
       array('Oct', 20),
       array('Nov', 23),
       array('Dec', 99)
    )
```

I tried to put those data that query from mysql database with the following code but still not what I want:

```
$get_date = dbQuery("SELECT MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(ors.order_date, '%Y-%m-%d')) AS month, SUM(ord.total_price) AS total FROM orders ors INNER JOIN order_detail ord ON (ors.order_id = ord.order_id) WHERE YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(ors.order_date, '%Y-%m-%d')) = '$year' GROUP BY month");
$count = $get_date->rowCount();
$index = 1;
$ar = array();
while($row = $get_date->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
    $ar[$index] = $row;
    $index++;
}
print_r($ar);
```

So my question is I want to put my data to the existing php array as I mentioned above, even if any month not available in mysql database the script still need to give that month as 0.

e.g if any month not exist in database then put data to the array like this

```
array(
       array('Jan', 27),
       array('Feb', 0),
       array('Mar', 56),
       array('Apr', 14),
       array('May', 0),
       array('Jun', 77),
       array('Jul', 0),
       array('Aug', 0),
       array('Sep', 81),
       array('Oct', 0),
       array('Nov', 23),
       array('Dec', 0)
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
array_push($data[0]['data'], [$month_name, $month_value]);
```

Perhabs this will work. Have not tested it.